# Disable shrinking spaces bar in El Capitan

Tags: software-update, spaces, macos, mission-control

I can't find a single piece of information about my issue. Is it possible to disable the 'feature' that the spaces bar reveals the content only if I hover with the mouse on it? It drives me nuts and I want the spaces bar to act like with the Yosemite update.

[image]

I want less space for the windows and more space for images of each virtual desktop by default.

Comment: What is a "shrinking spaces bar"?

Comment: @user3439894 When you're in Mission Control, the bar at the top contains the different spaces/desktops you've set up. In El Capitan you don't see the different spaces until you hover the bar, which is annoying.

Comment: Also, if you have 9 spaces not all are shown, the rightmost is hidden and you have to right scroll to it!  Usability == 0

Answer (score 3):

I made a utility for accomplishing this very thing. If you don't mind that it injects code into the Dock and requires disabling one part of System Integrity Protection, then give it a whirl:

https://github.com/briankendall/forceFullDesktopBar

That github page includes a release and installation instructions.

Comment: Yet another great use of mach_injection code by "the wolf" @rentzsch

Answer (score 1):

I find this **extremely** annoying. I the closest fix I have found was [TotalSpaces2](http://totalspaces.binaryage.com/documentation2), it's a paid app the manages your spaces. I would *really* recommend [sending feedback to Apple](http://apple.com/feedback)

Comment: Agree! I also would like spaces maximized by default.